# UFL u212com.dll that implements this function is missing

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a window service that generate a pdf report built in C#. The services built with 64 bit.
I move the service to window server 2016 (64 bit) and the server is installed

-Crystal report 2016 service pack 8

-Crystal for visual studio (SP27) 64 bit

-Barcodesoft code 128 font

The error comes from this line.

rptDoc.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, outputFileName + ".pdf");

Below is the error and the stacktrace

Error in File Test 6768_2448_{08C8795E-0B5D-4B49-9875-DD60960EDB0E}.rpt:
Error in formula  barcode: 
BCSLinearGS1128 ({Table1.barcode})
UFL u212com.dll that implements this function is missing.

at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ConvertDotNetToErom.ThrowDotNetException(Exception e)
at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.Export(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType formatType, String fileName)
at Mainworker.Main.ProcessFiles()

I check the server and u212com.dll is at "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win64_x64"

Any idea why i get this message?

Answer (score 2):

The ufl is probably 32-bit. Change service to 32-bit or obtain a 64-bit UFL.

Comment: MilletSoftware, I see the "u212com.dll" which the error saying missing in  "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win64_x64"

Comment: @Zola Like on SAP forums was told, you should not blindly trust their error messages - it could be possible that despite problem occurs at loading fonts package UFL through crystal com dll (u212com.dll), error does point at loader itself.

Comment: MilletSoftware, Thanks a lot ! After i degrade  service to 32 bit and install Crystal for visual studio (SP27) 32 bit resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have not installed your barcode fonts supporting software package correctly - this package should include custom COM DLL, which has to be registered properly.

See also SAP support: https://answers.sap.com/questions/12726499/ufl-u212comdll-that-implements-this-function-is-mi.html

Comment: Arvo, i built the rpt in the same server using Crystal report 2016 and the barcode work fine. But , The issue comes when i use that same rpt file in the  service. at same server

Comment: Are there some related events in event viewer? Under which account does your service run? Crystal Reports needs temporary folder; if your service account has no user profile folder, then Crystal uses windows\temp and may have not sufficient access rights to write there. How did you install fonts package - as administrator, I hope?

Comment: I don't see anything related to this issue in event viewer. Yes Fonts are instilled as Admin. The service account have r/w access to rpt file location. Even though,  the rpt are built in the same server. that i deploy the service, currently the rpt are in the different server., but the service have full access to that location .

Comment: Does service account have its profile folder (Users/something) or if not, then write access to windows\temp? But take a look @MilletSoftware answer too :)

Comment: Arvo, Thanks a lot ! After i degrade  service to 32 bit and install Crystal for visual studio (SP27) 32 bit the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The dll in the error message is just the ufl manager. It's a misleading error message.
Need the ufl dll that implements the BCSLinearGS1128() function.